# Google Ads - Negative conversion value

Tags: google-ads-api

I am wondering, if conversion value for Google AdWords Pixel could be negative?

Does anyone have experience with negative `google_conversion_value`?
My idea is to send contribution margins instead of revenue.

This is the example from help pages (https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6331314):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML-Beispieldatei</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <!-- Google-Code für Kauf-Conversion-Seite -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
    var google_conversion_label = "xxx-XXx1xXXX123X1xX";
    var google_remarketing_only = "false"
        var google_conversion_value = 10.0;
        var google_conversion_currency = "EUR"
    /* ]]> */ 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
    conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <img height=1 width=1 border=0 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
    conversion/1234567890/
    ?value=10.0&amp;currency_code=EUR&amp;label=xxx-   
    XXx1xXXX123X1xX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0">
           </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

negative values are not accepted from the [Google Ads Api](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7014069?hl=en)
see
[image]

what you can also do if you don´t want to expose your margin on the page: set up a Server 2 Server communication with Google Ads API (or simply via Google Sheet if you just want to test and avoid programming)

so summing up:

- On success page send no conversion value, only conversion pixel
- upload daily your conversion values using **Restate** or **Retract** logic

[image]